# How to prove that the segment $FG= DJ+EH$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

[image]

$BE, CD, AF$ are the angle bisectors of the $\triangle ABC$. A circle passes through the points $D, E, F$ and intersects the triangle again at $J, H, G$.  How to prove that $FG=DJ+EH$?

I tried to use  angle bisector theorem with  intersecting secant theorem and got some equations. Am I on the right track? Any hints or answers?

Comment: This is rather awkwardly worded problem since the vertices $A,B,C$ have symmetric roles in the statement but the conclusion is clearly not. Something implicitly must be assumed to guarantee $FG$ is the largest such segment.

Comment: Agree with @dezdichado, this is not generally true. Just play around with different shapes of $\triangle ABC$ can confirm it.

Comment: I got this result from a book. There was no information about configurations. Maybe this is only relevant for acute triangles

Comment: It seems to be true for any triangle. I think the correct statement of the problem is: "Prove that one of $FG,DJ,EH$ is the sum of two others".

Comment: The awkwardness is superficial. By use of directed segments, required to prove is a rather symmetrical property : $$\overline{FG}+\overline{DJ}+\overline{EH}=0$$

Comment: FYI, actually solving the equations (from the Angle Bisector Theorem and Intersecting Secants Theorem) gives that the *signed* distances along respective sides $a$, $b$, $c$ are
$$\frac{\left(\; 
  (b - c) (a b c - p^3 + 2 a p^2),
  (c - a) (a b c - p^3 + 2 b p^2),
  (a - b) (a b c - p^3 + 2 c p^2)
\;\right)}{2(a + b)(b + c)(c + a)} $$
where $p:=a+b+c$. The sum of these is readily seen to be zero, which accords with @cosmo5's restatement. Although solving isn't super-difficult, it's a little tedious. I'd like to think there's a more elegant approach.

Comment: @Blue, I think it might be easier to prove: $$a^4+b^4+c^4 = 2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2 +c^2a^2)$$
if $a,b,c$ are the lengths of these segments. This is the same as:
$$(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)(a+b+c) = 0$$
so the conclusion will follow without picking cases.

Comment: @dezdichado: That's a possibility, and a good way to think about the problem without signed distances. I was just doing a brute-force solution from the equations. ... Properly setup, though, there are no cases to pick. Effectively, you can just take the signed distances to be $x$, $y$, $z$ (which individually can be positive or negative) when doing, say, "counterclockwise" secant products, and $-x$, $-y$, $-z$ for "clockwise" secant products. Then $(x,y,z)$ is given by the expression in my previous comment via straightforward calculation; no case-picking required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Let the angle bisectors of $\triangle ABC$ meet the opposite sides at $D$, $E$, $F$, and let $\bigcirc DEF$ meet the sides again at $D'$, $E'$, $F'$. Define signed lengths $d:=|DD'|$, $e:=|EE'|$, $f:=|FF'|$, so that the task is to show $d+e+f=0$.

By the Intersecting Secants Theorem, using signed distances oriented with the vertex order $ABC$, we have
$$\begin{align}
|AF||AF'| = |EA||E'A| &\quad\to\quad |AF|(|AF|+|FF'|)=|EA|(|E'E|+|EA|) \\
&\quad\to\quad |AF|(|AF|+f)=|EA|(-e+|EA|) \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
By the Angle Bisector Theorem,
$$|AF| = |AB|\cdot \frac{|CA|}{|BC|+|CA|}=\frac{bc}{a+b} \qquad\qquad
|EA| = \frac{bc}{c+a} \tag{2}$$
so that $(1)$ becomes
$$(a + b)^2 (a + c) e +(a + b) (a + c)^2 f = b c (b - c) (2 a + b + c) \tag{3}$$
Likewise,
$$\begin{align}
(b + c)^2 (b + a) f +(b + c) (b + a)^2 d &= c a (c - a) (a + 2b + c) \\
(c + a)^2 (c + b) d +(c + a) (c + b)^2 e &= a b (a - b) (a + b + 2c) 
\end{align}\tag{4}$$
Solving yields
$$(d,e,f) = \frac{
\left(\;
 (b - c) (a b c - p^3 + 2 a p^2),
 (c - a) (a b c - p^3 + 2 b p^2),
 (a - b) (a b c - p^3 + 2 c p^2)
 \;\right)}{2 (a + b) (b + c) (c + a)}\tag{5}$$
where $p:=a+b+c$. From here, we readily see that $d+e+f=0$, as desired. $\square$

Answer (score 1):

This is just a suggestion and there must be some more eaiser and elegant ways.

Fact#1 Length of chord is equal to 2R sin x; where R is the radius of the respective circle and x is angle subtended by the chord at the circumference.

Fact#2 $\sin a + \sin b = 2 \sin (0.5(a + b)) \cos (0.5(a – b))$

To prove the required result, we need $2R \sin (large) = 2R \sin (medium) + 2R \sin (small)$. Which, in turn, is $\sin (large) = \sin (medium) + \sin (small)$. The RHS matches the LHS of fact #2.

The 0.5(a + b) and the 0.5(a – b) let me think of the angles formed by the near arc and the far arc.

Hope those can help. Good luck.